# Use foreach loop to assign postdata variable

Tags: php, foreach, postdata

I wonder if I can use foreach to optimize my code and avoid mistakes.

I have to set variable like that from postdata:

```
$a2 = $postdata->a2;    
$a3 = $postdata->a3;        
$a4 = $postdata->a4;
```

and so on...

I forgot one line, it cause trooble in my treatment.

I thought a code like that, but, I'm no sure it will works:

```
foreach($postdata as $key => $value) {  
            $"a2, a3, a4,..." = $postdata->"a2, a3, a4,...";
}
```

Thanks for helping me ;)

Comment: And what's the point in this?

Comment: the point is that I have a lot of variables from many php files.
I would like to simply add an include/function usign this code to automatize the process and be sure to get back the variable used in each file and no more, no less because if yes, the code will going wrong

Comment: I just worry that by automating that sort of thing (user input)... you could be opening yourself up to some dangerous situations.

Comment: I didn't thought on it

Comment: Assuming a stdObject, you could simply `extract( (array) $postdata)`, or you could `foreach($k => $v) { $$k = $v }`. But you do not want to do that with user input, which is never to be trusted. Because a bad person might send a POST request with additional variables that replace existing variables in your code, and break things, or worse.

Comment: Yes you're right @MarkusAO, that's what incredibleHat explained. Thx for your answer ;)